# Django Nginx Browser Caching Works Half-way

Tags: css, django, caching, nginx

I have this in my file in my /etc/nginx/sites-available/

```
upstream app_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /home/portforlio;
    index index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name khophi.co www.khophi.co;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    location /media  {
        alias /home/portfolio/media;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/portfolio/static;
    }

    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
        expires 30d;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
}
```

With the configuration above, I'm told I've leveraged files caching when I check via https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fkhophi.co%2F&tab=desktop

Yet, when I visit the site, it doesn't load the css and I get an unstyled page.

What is missing? I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26188032/nginx-browser-caching-with-alias) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27508683/django-nginx-browser-caching-configuration), yet although I have also specified my root directory, it still doesn't show them when requested in the browser.

Mysteriously, pageinsights sees them and even as cached, how?

the live site is at khophi.co

Answer (score 0):

The answer I figured out to be a typo.

Should be **portfolio** not *portforlio*

I added an error log to nginx and from there, I noticed it says the directory didn't exist, that prompted me to check the folder names

```
error_log /home/nginx/nginx_error.log warn;
```